# iOS App Crashes After Changing From iPhone to Universal:

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uialertcontroller

I'm getting an error from xCode stating:

```
2015-11-03 12:25:04.833 New Application[1122:1104042] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Your application has presented a UIAlertController (<UIAlertController: 0x14f68cb50>) of style UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet. The modalPresentationStyle of a UIAlertController with this style is UIModalPresentationPopover. You must provide location information for this popover through the alert controller's popoverPresentationController. You must provide either a sourceView and sourceRect or a barButtonItem.  If this information is not known when you present the alert controller, you may provide it in the UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate method -prepareForPopoverPresentation.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x182e1cf5c 0x19799ff80 0x188c50068 0x1886c0254 0x1886be384 0x18861c844 0x188628de4 0x1883651e4 0x182dd3c30 0x182dd19d4 0x182dd1e04 0x182d00dc0 0x18dca8088 0x1883daf60 0x1000f0d00 0x1981be8b8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

on the line:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
```

in:

```
//
//  AppDelegate.swift
//  FlappyBird
//
//  Created by Nate Murray on 6/2/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Fullstack.io. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }


}
```

found here:

My Source:
https://github.com/androiddeveloperfl/SADiver

Original Source:

https://github.com/fullstackio/FlappySwift/blob/master/FlappyBird/AppDelegate.swift

Any suggestions/answers/solutions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you read the error? Did you search on the key parts of the error?

Comment: @shim - yes it crashes as soon as it is launched - the project was handed to me in this state (the previous developer is no longer with us) what I have to go on is the current state of the code/project and the github link - that's it :/

Comment: yes - @rmaddy - I have - would you like to screenshot of the many many SO articles I have open which I've currently read in order to narrow down how to go about resolving this issue? I have read and searched through quite a few - however I still need to reach out to the community. (apologies @rmaddy)

Comment: Start with http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1 so you can narrow down where it is really crashing.

Comment: This is the most helpful article I've read all day - I'm the Android developer and I've been thrust into the world of iOS recently and I truly appreciate your help. I'll be back with more detailed debugging info after I step through it with breakpoints enabled etc :) 
Thank you sir!

Comment: Ok - I read the article and I'm familiar with the debugging process - I have breakpoints enabled is there some more detailed information I can provide? I still need a hand getting this running.

Comment: @shim - any idea what I can do regarding that observation? (thank you btw)

Comment: Did you narrow down where the actual crash is happening?

Comment: Somewhat... I can see the line it's crashing on - but I'm getting the same output as before after enabling breakpoints: (I'm still not sure how to resolve this - it seems like i need to catch an exception  - but im not sure)

Comment: Do I need to narrow it down to something more specific than the line number it's crashing at?

Comment: I really just need to fix this one bug (i'm not working on this long term) rather than pickup a complete understanding of xCode (I'll be assigned back to my daily Android tasks shortly - I'm just trying to resolve this crash in the meantime until they can hire [cough cough] another full time iOS developer.) :)

Comment: I just cloned the github repo and was able to build and run the app in the simulator and on a iPhone 6s with no crashes.  Is there any chance that something is off with your development environment or your checkout of the repo?  Try starting with a fresh clone and see if you get the same behavior.  Also, what version of xCode are you using and what device or simulator are you trying to run it on?  I just built it with xCode 7.1 and ran in in a 6s simulator and on a device running ios 9.1 if that helps

Comment: I've tried the same and I'm able to run it - my build env is good - the issue lies in the fact the previous developer made quite a few changes (several months worth) however left the app where it will run on an iPhone - just not an iPad - which is the issue I'm currently trying to solve. When I switch from iPhone to Universal or iPad we get the error shown above.

Comment: Here is my current source... perhaps it can be of assistance :) https://github.com/androiddeveloperfl/SADiver

Comment: I'm using xCode 7.1 as well and I'm attempting to run it on an iPad mini

Comment: I truly appreciate everyone's help btw - I'd be in a world of hurt without you.

Comment: So answer the question. What's the actual line of code where you're crashing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app is crashing when you are trying to present an action sheet in your `SplashViewController`.  On the iPad, an action sheet has a little arrow that points to a control or view that triggered the popup, and you need to tell it where to point.  In your code, in the `alert(title: String, message: String)`  function you could do something like;

```
    alertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
    alertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width / 2.0, self.view.bounds.size.height / 2.0, 1.0, 1.0)
```

which will put the arrow in the center of the view.  That probably looks odd though so you might also want to change the style of the UIAlertController from an action sheet to an alert:

```
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message:  message, preferredStyle: .Alert)
```

which looks better to me.  You then don't need to have the lines about the `popoverPresentationController`

Answer (score 0):

When you summon an action sheet on an iPad, it is a popover. That means you must state where the popover arrow will point. Get the alert's popover presentation controller and give it this information as you present the alert.

Here's an example:

```
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)
    func handler(act:UIAlertAction!) {
        print("User tapped \(act.title)")
    }
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: handler))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Hey", style: .Default, handler: handler))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ho", style: .Default, handler: handler))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Hey Nonny No", style: .Default, handler: handler))
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    // if we do no more than that, we'll crash on iPad
    // here's how to fix that:
    if let pop = alert.popoverPresentationController {
        let b = sender as! UIBarButtonItem
        pop.barButtonItem = b // or set sourceView and sourceRect
    }
```

Comment: I appreciate your example - I found something similar when researching the solution for this issue. In this instance I'm looking for any code relating to popovers in the original source the previous dev forked which does infact run on iPad for clues as to how I might do the same in mine but I see no references when searching the entire project - any idea why that might be?

Original: (working on iPad)
https://github.com/fullstackio/FlappySwift
Mine: (not working on iPad) 
https://github.com/androiddeveloperfl/SADiver